# Best way of structuring documents in Cloud Firestore (NoSQL databases)?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, structure

I am trying to implement a Firestore Cloud DB but I am new to NoSQL databases.

I want to know whats the best way of arranging these sets into collections/documents:

I have **restaurants** which have different **foods** and **reservations**. What would be the best approach to structure these sets of data into Firestore DB?

Is this a right approach:

```
Restaurant1 (Collection)
----> Foods (document) 
----> Reservations (document)
```

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?

Comment: @AlexMamo For example, Users will make reservations, will reserve food, will display description,food and all details of one restaurant, etc.

Comment: "will reserve food" doesn't seem like a query and the other are related to displaying details rather than querying/searching something.

Comment: There will be a restaurant`s side app and the clients app. So lets say when a client makes a reservation, the restaurant´s management should be able to see his reservation together with other reservations from other clients, in a list. And each client should be able to see his history of reservations as well. This is just an example because there will be much more than these functionalities.

Comment: If you think that it will be helful for you, I can try to provide you a schema which suits this queries: *the restaurant´s management should be able to see his reservation together with other reservations from other clients, in a list. And each client should be able to see his history of reservations as well.*. Without knowing other queries I cannot be much of a help.

Comment: That would be very helpful to me, feel free to add other queries that you may think I will need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment:

> the restaurant´s management should be able to see his reservation together with other reservations from other clients, in a list. And each client should be able to see his history of reservations as well.

I'll try to provide you a schema that can help you get that data very easily.

```
Firestore-rrot
   |
   --- users (collection)
   |    |
   |    --- uid (document)
   |    |    |
   |    |    --- type: "manager"
   |    |
   |    --- uid (document)
   |         |
   |         --- type: "client"
   |
   --- reservations (collection)
        |
        --- reservationIdOne (document)
        |       |
        |       --- reservedBy: "uid"
        |       |
        |       --- date: September 21, 2019 at 1:15:02 PM UTC+3
        |
        --- reservationIdTwo (document)
                |
                --- reservedBy: "uid"
                |
                --- date: September 21, 2019 at 1:18:42 PM UTC+3
```

Using this schema, you can simply query the database to get all users or specific users (manager or clients). You can also get all reservations by adding a reference on `reservations` collection. If you want to get the reservation only of a single type (manager or client), you should use a query that might look like this:

```
db.collection("reservations").whereEqual("type", "manager");
```

As you can see, I have also added a `date` property so you can easily sort them descending (last reservation first).

Comment: this looks good, but I just came up with three more changes: First, I need users separated because managers will not be able to register themselves so I will have to add them manually to db, second, there are "discounts" that restaurants will make and publish so clients can see them, and third, there will be "orders" as well so when a client sees a discount on food he can order that. Whats the best way to add these to the schema?

Comment: Regarding your first question, there is no need to add them separately, you can add them in a single collection as suggested in my answer and later distinguish them using a query. Second, I hope you **can** understand that I can't refactor the schema everytime you have a new idea about a query. That's the main reason I have asked you from the beginning, what are the queries that you intend to perform and you agreed with the one from the comment. Beside that, it will be very simple to create another collection of restaurants and add a discount property for each one of them.

Comment: Regarding the third question, you can solve it in the same way, by creating a new collection of orders and once a user creates a new order in a specific restaurant, use the discount that exist in that specific restarant.

Comment: alright Alex thanks for taking the time to answer my questions.

Answer (score 3):

I think storing Foods and Reservations as top level collections will ultimately yield you more flexibility later on.

It's easy enough to take a restaurantID and stick it in the each document in those collections, so I don't personally think you should nest them in the Restaurants collection. It's a personal preference from working with a lot of nested collections.

I think the optimal structure is:

```
Restaurants (collection)
--- Name: Chipotle
--- ID: restaurant1
--- Foods: [{ Name: foodItem1 }, { Name: foodItem2 }]

Foods (collection)
--- Name: foodItem1
--- Ingredients: abc
--- Nutrition Facts: xyz

Reservations (collection)
--- User: user1
--- Restaurant: { id: restaurant1, name: Chipotle }
--- Time: 3pm

Users (collection)
--- ID: user1
```

What you'll notice is there is some redundant info. This is good so if you request all reservations, you'll get the restaurant's name and ID, etc. stuff you would likely want. You will find you'll want to store data multiple times and this to me feels like a good structure for it.

With this structure you can very easily just call:

`All reservations by user X` or `All foods meeting nutrition limits of Y`

Instead of a collectionGroup query which would call for all restaurants' sub collection list of reservations. You won't always want to query your reservations by restaurant, maybe you want to pull by user or time, etc.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, I will consider them while creating my DB :)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the use-case you are trying to solve, as you should be optimizing for specific queries on those models.

I recommend watching these videos to get a better idea:

- Series of [What is a NoSQL Database? How is Cloud Firestore structured?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35RlydUf6xo)
- [Model Relational Data in Firestore NoSQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jm66TSlVtcc)
- [Firestore Data Modeling - Five Cool Techniques](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35RlydUf6xo)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I will take a look at those videos!